# Stopping an Azure Service does *not* stop the WebJob's continuously running behind it

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure WebJob that is running on a pretty simple App Service `Standard: 1 Small` (plan).

Now, there was a problem with my WebJob (which has 5 functions running) - I wanted to stop 4 of the 5 *running* functions. I couldn't see how, so I thought I'd just stop the entire WebJob instead.

So I ended up just **stopping the App Service**.

[image]

Great, that was stopped, but the WebJob was still running and I didn't notice that until a few hours later.

I later noticed that the WebJob blade has its *own* Start/Stop button.

[image]

I thought the WebJobs were tied directly to the App Service.

What is the connection between the two? How does one affect that other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the web app and web jobs has different process in the azure.

You could find the Process explorer in the web portal as below:

[image]

So the stop in the web app will just closed the app's process(6584 as the image shows).

It will not stop the webjob's process(4648).

These two processes has no connection.

If you want to stop both web app process and webjobs process, I suggest you could try to use this way [Full stopping a Web App](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Full-stopping-a-Web-App).

Comment: So why is a webjob _part_ of an App Service?

Comment: In my opinion, Azure WebJobs provide an easy way to run scripts or programs as background processes on App Service Web Apps. Since it  use the azure web app's resource to run the background processes, it is the  part of an App service.  Now the stop in the azure web app just stop the  web app's site IIS process, it will not stop the KUDU(scm) tool's IIS process.  So it will not auto stop the webjob.

Comment: Yes, Brando is correct. Note that you can stop individual continuous WebJobs via the WebJobs UI.